# Netlogo - Graphics window grows every time model is opened (patch size < 1)

Tags: netlogo

In Netlogo, I have to change the **patch size** to <1 in order to fit the graphics window on my computer screen. For example, from 1 to 0.5.

This works well; however, once I save the file, close it, and reopen, the graphics window (not coordinates - but the physical size of the window on my computer) is back to its previous size.

When I check the patch size however, it is still 0.5. Now for my model to fit, I must make the patch 0.25. This is a cycle, and I eventually need to make the patch size ridiculously small like 0.001.

I am using Netlogo 6.1.1 and have only used the Model Settings Box to modify patch size. I have attached screenshots of this behavior :

[image]

I understand that the patch size does not affect the model functionality, however, I would like to fix this so that the model is presentable.

Has anyone run into this issue, or has any idea of how to avoid/fix it?
Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Very weird. I won't be able to answer this, but I just want to confirm some details. Does the size change happens when you open NetLogo without a model (so a new, blank model), or when you open a model, or when you open a specific model?

Comment: Thank for the reply. It happens in both cases. The screenshots above were created using a blank model, but it happens in my own specific model as well. It only seems to be an issue when the patch size is below 1.

Comment: Just to rephrase, it can happen to any model (blank or not), but only seems to start happening if the patch-size has been changed to less than 1.

Comment: Known issue (that seems unlikely to ever get fixed): https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/409

Comment: Thanks @SethTisue, I hadn't known about it, a bit of a shame. This does answer my question, however. I don't have rep to upvote comments but if you submit this as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: So all you have to do is set the patch size to 1 every time just before you save the file and then when you open it set the patch size to .5 again?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes exactly, that's the solution essentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known NetLogo issue, and it would probably be rather difficult for the NetLogo developers to fix it. (I know, I used to be one of them.)

Details are here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/409